# Ember app renders blank page when typing in a specific URL

Tags: ember.js, nginx

In my Ember app, if I'm developing locally I can directly go to a page by going to the url `http://localhost:4200/some/page`. I can also navigate to that page within the app itself.

However, after my app is deployed and I go to `https://dev.myapp.com` I am able to navigate around the site just fine but if I try to go to a url directly (such as `https://dev.myapp.com/some/page`) there is nothing rendered in the browser and the DOM is completely empty. But if I enter `https://dev.myapp.com/` back into the browser I am able to start navigating the app again.

Would this have to do with how I build or deploy my app or is this something that I might have configured wrong within the Ember app itself?

I should also add that I am using Nginx to deploy my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're working with [history based locations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API), Ember modifies the browser URL during navigation but no actual document GET request is made to the web server. When you refresh and request a specific route directly, the webserver attempts to serve a corresponding file, which fails because the file does not exist.

You will have to tell your webserver to always serve index.html regardless which file is requested and then let Ember do the magic. The detailled configuration depends on your webserver.

This works for me on Apache 2:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

The old Ember App Kit documentation has [more examples](http://iamstef.net/ember-app-kit/guides/deployment.html) at the page bottom.

Comment: Would that be similar to using "index index.html index.htm;" with nginx? This is from the ember-cli website

Comment: Or would it be the line "try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?/$request_uri;"?

Comment: I am not familiar with nginx but I believe that this is indeed the most important line. It specifies the order in which a specific resource is attempted to be accessed, see [corresponding nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more info. If it cannot be accessed as an actual, existing file or directory, it falls back to index.html where Ember does the magic, parses the URI and transitions to the corresponding route.

Comment: I think this was part of the issue. the other part had to do with how we had set up our passenger config. But this definitely helped us solve the issue!